# Best practice for handling null with dependency injection c#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

If I have

```
IMyService _myService;
public MyController(IMyService myService){
    _myService = myService;
}
```

and I'm using say unity to resolve my dependency...

Is it best practice to check if myService is null and if so should I throw an excpetion or create a new concrete implementation?

Comment: Won't unity throw something like *cannot resolve IMyService dependency* exception? For manual inserting of dependencies you can add null-check and there is ArgumenNullException which you should throw if argument not supposed to be null

Comment: Unless null represents a valid state for the dependency, I would say not, and in fact, add a `Contract.Requires` or guard to ensure that it isn't null - this would be a bug in the DI setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, Unity will not provide `null` as parameter value. It either will create instance of type registered for `IMyService`, or it will throw exception:

> Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type IMyService does not
>   have an accessible constructor.
>
> ---
>
> At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving Foo.MyController,(none)
>
> Resolving parameter "myService" of constructor
>   Foo.MyController(Foo.IMyService myService)   Resolving
>   Foo.IMyService,(none)

So, there is nothing to worry about `null` injected by Unity (or other dependency injection framework). But if controller can be instantiated manually it is possible that someone will pass `null` to constructor. Passing `null` is a very bad smell - that means something went wrong in your system. So, best option is checking service value and throw ArgumentNullException:

```
public MyController(IMyService myService)
{
    if (myService == null)
       throw new ArgumentNullException("myService");

    _myService = myService;
}
```

If injection of service should be optional. Then I suggest you to use *property injection* instead of *constructor injection*.

Comment: Yeah I was talking about if somebody were to try and create an isnatnce of my object. I know that the resolver wouldn't provide null. So it seems I should be throwing an exception not creating an isnatnce.

Comment: @Simon you can use Poor Man's Dependency Injection (i.e. create parameterless constructor, which will create default instance of service and pass it to your current constructor) but you still have to check service for null and throw if somebody passed wrong argument value

Comment: I want to avoid poor mans. Just wanted to double check the best practice for checking for null so thanks for the answer.

Comment: Property Injection requires you to download the unity package in the referenced DLL because you need to decorate the dependency with `Dependency` attribute that is available in the unity assembly. That's the only disadvantage trying to avoid

Comment: I'm seriously thinking about removing all our null-checks in constructors, because we use DI for everything and this just decreases our unit-testing conditional-coverage result a lot (or we will need to start adding unit-tests for testing the null case which will never occur)...

Answer (score 1):

If it's okay for the dependency to be null (in which case it is by definition not a dependency, by the way), you should make it an optional parameter.

```
IMyService _myService;
public MyController(IMyService myService = null){
    _myService = myService;
}
```

In all other cases, throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: I wouldn't ever want it to be null so will go with throwing an exception. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nope, if you are working with a DI framework that framework has to throw an exception when it can't resolve the dependency. You never create a concrete implementation thath is the whole point of use an inyector for your dependencies. Imagine you add:

```
if (myServices == null) _myService = new ConcreteService()
```

If you do that when you make the unit test for that controller if you choose to test the scenario when you passa a null IMyService you will be unable to mock that object because you are not inyecting it.

Comment: Indeed. Just writing my tests now to check for the exception!

Answer (score 0):

The Dependency Injection Provider should prevent you from injecting null references.

If you want to for some reasons inject the depenecy manually and null reference is not expected you can add null-checking as a pretty one-line expression with `null-coalescing operator` `??` and throw `ArgumentNullException` including the name of injected reference.

> The null-coalescing operator ?? returns the value of its left-hand
> operand if it isn't null; otherwise, it evaluates the right-hand
> operand and returns its result. The ?? operator doesn't evaluate its
> right-hand operand if the left-hand operand evaluates to non-null.

```
private readonly IMyService _myService;
public MyController(IMyService myService)
{
    _myService = myService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myService));
}
```